# How to get the longest height of the div from pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to achieve what can be achieved via jQuery but I'm avoiding jQuery for learning javascript. I'm trying to get the highest number from `.map`. This is what I've done so far.

```
function equalHeight(className) {
  var i = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className));
  i.forEach(function(items) {
    console.info(Math.max(items.scrollHeight));
  });
}
```

but this logs nothing

```
console.info(items.scrollHeight);
```

logs all three numbers.

I know I'm missing an **elementary** mistake, Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Basically, I want to get the longest height and set it to the rest of the divs

Comment: Your code works fine. Need to see the HTML & CSS to determine what is not working for you. That is what is meant by a [Minimal, Complete & Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @RandyCasburn Point taken, but I posted this question after reviewing HTML and CSS and did `console.info(items.scrollHeight);`, so clearly the problem was in my javascript code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not 100% sure exactly what you are after, but a few things:

1) Switching from `getElementsByClassName` to `querySelectorAll` gives you an object that has `forEach` built in.

2) You were passing in only 1 value to `Math.max`

```js
function equalHeight(className) {
  var max = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll(className).forEach(
    function(el) {
      console.info(Math.max(el.scrollHeight, max));
      if (el.scrollHeight > max) {
        max = el.scrollHeight;
      }
    }
  );
  
  return max;
}

var max = equalHeight('.test');

console.info('Max div height:', max);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">one</div>
<div class="test">one<br/>two</div>
<div class="test">one<br/>two<br/>three</div>
```

**UPDATE**

To your question "now how do I use this value as height for the rest of the divs":

```js
function getMaxHeight(className) {
  var max = 0;
  document.querySelectorAll(className).forEach(
    function(el) {
      console.info(Math.max(el.scrollHeight, max));
      if (el.scrollHeight > max) {
        max = el.scrollHeight;
      }
    }
  );
  
  return max;
}

function setHeight(className, height) {
  document.querySelectorAll(className).forEach(
    function(el) {
      el.style.height = height+'px';
    }
  );
}


var max = getMaxHeight('.test');

console.info('Max div height:', max);

setHeight('.test', max);
```

```css
div {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  margin: 2px 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">one</div>
<div class="test">one<br/>two</div>
<div class="test">one<br/>two<br/>three</div>
```

But, once you do this then none of the DIVs will change height again.

You could set `el.style.minHeight` and then, check again if you change anything in the DIVs.

Comment: Okay, point taken, but, I'm passing an entire Object in `Math.max`, shouldn't that suffice to give out maximum number from the Object?

Comment: `Mat.max` wants numbers and not objects. You could change the code to convert from an array of Objects into an array of heights and then pass them in to `Math.max.apply(Math, arrayOfVals)`

Comment: Quick question: now how do I use this value as height for the rest of the divs?

Comment: Works like charm

Answer (score 1):

I would use `.getBoundingClientRect()` and just compare for every iteration

```
function equalHeight(className) {
  const elements = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(className));
  let highest = 0;

  elements.forEach(function(item) {
     const itemH = item.getBoundingClientRect().height;
     highest = itemH > highest ? itemH : highest;
  });

  return highest;
}
```

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect